# Add remote to origin

Tags: git

I'm looking for an option to push my remote configuration to origin.
Locally I have 2 remote sources I work with. I would like to push this information to our origin so the fresh clone from origin will contain both remotes. Is that possible?

local repository my_repo:

```
git remote add remote2 http://some-url.git
# magic command here
```

fresh repository my_repo:

```
git clone my_repo
cd my_repo
git fetch remote2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Git has any option to add remotes automatically.

You could probably write a script to add the `remote2` folder in `.git/refs/remotes/`, or you could simply ask your repository's collaborators to add the new remote manually. It's very straightforward:

```
git remote add remote2 http://some-url.git
git fetch remote2
```

Answer (score 1):

Git has no built-in functionality to push its configuration between repositories.